# Dynamicly build string path for curl capath

Tags: bash, curl, ssl-certificate, expand

Curl has the option to add capath as one of its arguments.
This argument can contain one path or several paths in this format:

```
curl --capath /certs/path1:/certs/path2:/certs/path3 https://domain.com
```

Is it possible to use curl capath arg with subfolders by only adding the root dir such as  /certs/ ?
And if not i would like to build the string which automatically expands to this 
format:  /certs/path1:/certs/path2:/certs/path3

When i echo this command :

```
echo /certs/*

/certs/path1 /certs/path2 /certs/path3
```

required output:

```
/certs/path1:/certs/path2:/certs/path3
```

The idea is to have some automatic expanding method that will do that without sed awk or external tool.

something like this:

```
curl --capath /certs/*{:} https://domain.com
```

will automatlcy result with :
    curl --capath /certs/path1:/certs/path2/:/certs/path3 https://domain.com

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't see any way to do it without an externl program.
Well, you could do

```
for s in /certs/*
do
  path+="$s:"
done
```

But I don't think you are looking for this.
The point is that you are using the wildcard character '*' and it is interpreted by your shell as a list of string, separated with space.

Else just put in a variable

```
var=`/certs/* | tr ' ' ':'`
```

Hope this will answer. And if someone can find a real solution, then I want to know it too =)

Comment: echo /certs/* |  sed 's/ /:/g ; s/\*//' will also result with this: /certs/path1:/certs/path2:/certs/path3     but im trying to avoid sed awk tr or staff like that but thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, I give you a for loop that can create a string only using your script.
But I understand your problem and I don't know any solution for you. except with another program.